# Is Immanuel Wallerstein's theory on capitalism and cognitive dissonance empirically verifiable?

Tags: political-theory, racism, capitalism, empirical-studies

In the past I have heard people assert that racism is caused by capitalism, and this has never really made sense to me.

However, [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/70214) references a theory by Immanuel Wallerstein that explains how capitalism leads to racism. In a nutshell, capitalism causes inequality, and inequality causes cognitive dissonance (the wealthy like the existing system but also feel guilty about it). To relieve the dissonance, the wealthy shift poverty onto an easily identifiable group (such as a specific race) so they can believe that it is the group's fault that they are poor, not the system's fault.

This makes a lot of sense to me, but it is not obvious to me whether it is true. Is there a way to empirically verify whether this theory holds water? I can imagine a psychological study could verify that inequality causes guilt and cognitive dissonance, but how would one verify that people repsond to the cognitive dissonance by shifting poverty onto people who are "other"?

Comment: That depends on what Wallerstein means. If they are saying that this is something that can happen, they are certainly correct: conservative parties in the USA have used this strategy before with Black Americans and immigrants. If they are saying that capitalism is the cause of everything that could be considered racist, writ large, that is probably unprovable: things that would be considered racist in a modern sense certainly existed before capitalism, but with [a broad enough meaning of capitalism, anything is possible.](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_omnium_malorum_avaritia?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: Um... So there is no inequality before capitalism or in places that don't have it? And people only feel guilty about being wealthy when they got it through free trade? Sorry, but soon I will need to channel Norm Macdonald.

Answer (score 3):

While it would be hard to claim that no instance of capitalism has ever caused racism, it doesn't seem all that hard to find cases of racism that had little to do with it.

- Rwanda with the Tutsi/Hutu mess (which predated Belgium's nasty colonialism, even if Belgium exacerbated it on purpose, as a way to tie Tutsi fortunes to Belgian governance)?
- India with the [caste system](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/blogs/jugglebandhi/the-indian-caste-system-is-based-on-racism/)? How much "capitalism" is involved?
- Most of all, [historical European anti-semitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_antisemitism), before the advent of capitalism, where Jewish people were at least partially targeted because they were perceived as rich?  (Never mind that religious edicts channelled them towards jobs like banking which were forbidden to Christians).
- The Spanish kingdom's unpleasant history of slavery and native oppression to extract gold in South America.  Considering that Adam Smith's Wealth of Nations was at least partially a criticism of Spain's gold-based approach to wealth creation, calling it capitalist would be a stretch.

OK, what if it just a question of "wealth", rather than "capitalism"?

Then consider that you might confusing correlation with causation: if you can suppress/confiscate the wealth of minorities you oppress then you will be richer than them.

Naming capitalism as "the cause" seems far-fetched (but quite likely to correlate with increased book sales).

Comment: Just so it's said, the caste system in India was not particularly problematic until the British weaponized it to establish political and economic hegemony, anti-semitism in Europe traces back to the fact that Jews were sanctioned as money-lenders (perhaps the earliest capitalist form), and Adam Smith's Free Market theories where his idealized (and unobtainable) form of capitalism, not a definition of what capitalism *is*.

Comment: Citations on the caste system claims are forthcoming, right?

Comment: Was that directed at me? Well, I don't usually do citations, but I'll take a look. What I know off-hand is that the caste system was originally part of the karmic worldview: caste was a reflection of spiritual attainment, and one was expected to rise in caste over the course of many rebirths. But the British formalized the caste system, giving Brahmins political authority as provincial rulers (with British military aid) in order to maximize expropriation of resources. But I'll get back to you...

Comment: @TedWrigley - To blame "capitalism" for anti-Semitism by saying that Jews were "sanctioned as money-lenders" seems a little problematic to me. Jews were largely forced into the profession of money-lending by their exclusion from most professions and often from land ownership. In other words, anti-Semitism came first and (along with Christian interpretations of prohibitions against usury) *caused* Jews to be more likely to have to take up professions such as money-lending, *not* the other way around.

Comment: Furthermore, giving the British Raj full credit for making the Indian caste system a problem is too charitable. I think few historians would deny that they worsened it; however, it was certainly not innocuous before. Of course it was expected that if a Dalit, for instance, behaved ethically they would be reborn as a higher class. But that hardly implied the absence of discrimination or exclusion in their current life. For instance, the Manusmṛiti recommends the exclusion of Dalits. There are thought to be many interpolations in the text, but not *that* recent.

Comment: Like, yes, the caste system certainly became more rigid, widespread, and harmful during the Raj; that is well-attested. But to assert that it was "not problematic" before requires the dismissal of a good deal of historical evidence. The historian [Vivekanand Jha](http://ddkosambi.blogspot.com/2013/01/untouchability-gita-and-pursuit-of-truth.html?m=1) asserted, for instance, that untouchability developed well before the Raj or even the Mughal period, between 600 and 1200 AD.

Comment: With reason: take a look at the article "A Historical Analysis of Segregation of Untouchable Castes in North India from Circa 600 A.D. to 1200 A.D." for some discussion of the contemporary sources that illustrate the presence of discrimination against occupations, many of which would become the various Dalit castes.

Comment: @Obie2.0 wow, that's quite a lot of details.  I'm still waiting for Ted's citations, keeping in mind that my own linked article about castes had this to say: *Barring the Andaman and Nicobar tribals, the other four population groups mingled and intermarried till about the 6th century AD.  Then, sometime during the Gupta period of about 1600 years ago, laws based on scriptural and social proscriptions created exclusivist divisions which prohibited intermarriage between these different genetic, or ethnic, groups.*.

Comment: Now I have no doubt that British Raj took full advantage of whatever they could manipulate in Indian society to further their own aims.  But to claim that "no problem with castes, it was all the British's fault" needs a lot more backup than "because it suits my argument".

Comment: @ItalianPhilospher - In light of Ted Wrigley's apparent argument that (modern, traditional) forms of capitalism might be the root cause of the caste system, it is interesting to note that Jha was a Marxist historian (not as an insult, that was the historiographical tradition to which he belonged), and that from my amateur perspective, due to the nexus between left-wing and pro-Dalit politics, Marxist historians seem to be fairly likely to emphasize a longer history of caste discrimination in India (don't forget that Marx was not a great fan of feudalism, either).

Comment: @ItalianPhilos - Well, recent research suggests that the caste system is probably largely more recent than 1600 years ago, and that it was more rigid during the Mughal and particularly Raj periods with regard to things like intermarriage than it had been in the past. It seems popular these days to argue that the core of the modern caste system really emerged in the period that I indicated.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Jews did the money-lending business because biblical law (as it was interpreted until late in the 2nd millennium), forbade Christians from lending money to Christians at interest. That was a significant sin that Jews (as Jews) did not have to worry about. Loaning money at interest is a defining feature of capitalism (it's one of the main ways of raising capital). We can debate the chicken/egg question of which came first (though I'll note that there wasn't much prejudice against Jews even into the 5th/6th centuries). But Jews were the *only* capitalists until (maybe) the 16th century

Comment: @Obie2.0: *Nobody* likes a money lender.

Comment: I am curious as to whether you realize how the (incorrect) statement that "Jews were the only capitalists until the 16th century" sounds, particularly coming from someone who (I presume) has a perspective that is not too favorable towards capitalism. "Capitalism is bad and Jews created capitalism" verges quite close toward popular anti-Semitic ideas.

Comment: @Obie2.0: But at any rate, I didn't say that Capitalism was the only source of racism. I said that Capitalism *requires* racism (in my understanding of Wallerstein's work). If racism exists, capitalism will use it; if racism doesn't exist, capitalism will create it. In non-ideal forms of capitalism, someone needs to be exploited to maximize profits. Someone needs to *lose*, and human psychology needs to find some explanation s for why people lose than sheer random chance.

Comment: @Obie2.0: You assume wrong about my leanings, though in retrospect 14th century would have been a better line to draw than 16th. Though I do suspect you're confusing those who developed wealth from tithes, taxes, estate resources, and rents (i.e., the old aristocracy) with capitalists proper (e.g., the bourgeoisie).

Comment: Sure, you *could* debate which came first, but it is pretty clear. Antiochus IV was passing anti-Jewish laws before the birth of Jesus of Nazareth. There were anti-Jewish riots in 3rd-century Alexandria. Anti-Semitism was not invented in 6th-century Europe. And although people's antipathy toward money-lenders, in conjunction with their belief that "Jews are money-lenders," undoubtedly worsened anti-Semitism, [the overwhelming majority of Jews were never engaged in money-lending](https://jewishstudies.washington.edu/global-judaism/debunking-myth-jewish-elites-bankers-europe-history/).

Comment: It would further be a grave historiographical error to focus on the exclusion of Christians from money-lending as a primary factor in the prevalence of Jews in the field without considering the fact that the [exclusion of Jews from guilds](https://scholarworks.seattleu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1182&context=suurj) pushed skilled Jews toward a small set of occupations. Pay particular attention to this line: "Barred from practicing any craft, the only two
options available to a Jewish person were to become a moneylender or a long-distance trader."

Answer (score -8):

Yes it can be easily disproved. One of the more drastic disproofs is [The Most Important Graph in the World.](https://reason.com/2016/12/13/the-most-important-graph-in-the-world/)  For thousands of years there was no meaningful increase in wealth in the entire world. Every means and method of societal arrangement was tried. People bounced around on the ragged edge of starvation, often below that edge.

Then, near the end of the 18th century, capitalism was invented. The result was an explosion of wealth. It is an exponential increase such that it is quite possible that within 20 years we could see the near eradication of absolute poverty. No other arrangement of society has ever done anything to lift people out of poverty. Only capitalism has done so, and it has done so world wide for 2 centuries.

[image]

The notion that capitalism can only enrich people at other's expense is wrong. Massively and clearly wrong. One might almost call it culpably wrong. Capitalism enriches the people who engage in voluntary trade. The well-known win-win trade arises only in voluntary free exchange. If it isn't win-win then people won't voluntarily engage in it. If they are not voluntarily engaging in it, then it is only going to be win-win by sheerest accident.

The notion that inequality didn't exist before capitalism, or that it does not exist today in non-capitalist countries, is just silly. The notion that racism only exists or arose only where capitalism exists is also just silly. Satraps and kings and warlords exist and existed long before capitalism.

====

Correlation does not equal causality. Yes. But at no point did I claim that.

All of history produced no enrichment. None. Zero. No form of government, no form of society, no arrangement of people produced anything but stagnation. Freedom arose and POOF! Freedom arose in another country and SHAZAM! Freedom is predicted to produce enrichment in other countries. Freedom is instituted and BIG VIOLINS! Wealth follows.

Put not your faith in princes becaue princes produce stagnation. Then global substitute for "princes" every other form of government or society organization and note that 2000 years of history clearly show they don't raise people out of poverty. Then note that people who have been raised out of poverty were so done by capitalism. Not by some unknown mechanism but explitly and openly by capitalism. Win-win trades openely arrived at with force banned. People doing what their own self interest dictates. People free to choose their own path. The rising tide raises all boats.

At the same link is the next graph. The interesting thing here is not that world per-capita GDP is increasing exponentially. Which it is. It is that it is increasing fastest where there is more freedom.

We do not have to guess how this happened. We can go ask the people involved in it. Freedom means they can choose to participate in trades that are good for them. Lack of freedom pushes them off these choices. It is entirely open and clear. Capitalism produces these things as predicted. In the manner predicted.

[image]

Comment: This answer is very wrong. To begin with, the notion of a "capitalist" is attested from the 17th century, not the end of the 18th century. It would also be a mistake to believe that capitalism only came into existence when the word was invented: the East India Company, for instance, dates  to the 1500s and is widely considered an early capitalist entity. Further, limited forms of capitalism go back much further: some of the first joint-stock companies are attested in Tang China, for instance. That also undermines the argument presented in the answer.

Comment: Then, the graph presented is massively misleading in the context of the argument. To start with, it is an estimate of real GDP, but what matters for quality of life is closer to real GDP per capita, and the human population has been *growing*. That significantly reduces apparent GDP per capita growth during the period considered. Even worse, there are serious problems with estimating historical GDP from time periods without adequate record-keeping and with completely different technology and lifestyles.

Comment: Which of course brings us to the most significant problem: correlation versus causation. This answer implicitly gives capitalism the credit for any increases in real wealth over the last few centuries. However, this period was also home to significant technological progress and social developments apart from capitalism, such as dramatic population increases. Does growth cause capitalism? Does technological development cause both? Is it a mere historical coincidence that the two started around the same time? The graph certainly does not establish what is claimed.

Comment: There is also problems with suggesting that absolute poverty may be nearly eliminated within 20 years, because this is strongly threshold-dependent. With a threshold set at $1.90 per day (2011 PPP), the number of people in absolute poverty is decreasing relatively rapidly, but with a threshold set at $10 per day, the number of people in absolute poverty is actually increasing. Attributing these decreases to capitalism also seems dubious: the most significant changes occurred after 1960 and particularly after 2000, hardly directly corresponding to an explosion of capitalism.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't proof of your point, and isn't precisely what I would call reasoned argument. It's mainly an assertion of Right-Libertarian articles of faith. I mean, no one argues that science and technology haven't raised the standard of living for most people in the Western world (and many people in the third world). I might dispute the relationship of science and technology to capitalism, but that discussion wouldn't go anywhere, so let it slide. The problem is that simply brushes the notion of exploitation under the catch-phrase 'voluntary free exchange'.

Comment: I mean, sure, the average Uber driver has things a 14th century serf couldn't dream of: a car, a cell phone, a living space not built of timber and wattle and thatch. but like a medieval serf, an Uber driver has to work 14-16 hour days to make ends meet, because most of the earnings of his labor go to to the Gig Bros at Uber, who spend it on the finest things. And if that driver gets fired, or injured, or has to take care of a sick family member... Well, he's about a month away from living like an *actual* 14th century serf when he can 't pay his rent. What's 'free' or 'voluntary' about that?

Comment: The edit makes your answer make even less sense. "All of history" produced no enrichment before capitalism according to your argument, which also began in the late 18th century, also according to you. This dismisses a tremendous history of technological innovation, which raised people's real wealth in substantive ways. The invention of agriculture and subsequent innovations such as irrigation, crop rotation, and the moldboard plow, which allowed for a steady supply of food unconstrained by the seasons? The invention of buildings?

Comment: The development of techniques to smelt and forge an ever-greater variety of useful metals? According to your argument, the average 17th-century person, with access to year-round food, vessels, bedding, and a building in which to live, was no wealthier in a modern sense than a pre-Neolithic hunter-gatherer. Quality of life is somewhat subjective, and a given pre-Neolithic hunter-gatherer may well have felt more contented than the average 17th-century person, but from the perspective of any modern notion of "wealth" in terms of production, this is still an incredible argument.

Comment: And then apparently *only* free, capitalist countries produce wealth! This certainly goes against any conventional economic thought. How about the Soviet Union, a country that was neither particularly free nor certainly capitalist? It had more or less steady GDP per capita growth (adjusted for PPP) from 1922 through 1990! It certainly did not become one of the two primary superpowers through zero wealth creation.

Comment: @Obie2.0 You say "only" where I said "fastest." Kind of whacky that you would lie and then get up-thumbs.

Comment: "Then global substitute for 'princes' every other form of government or society organization and note that 2000 years of history clearly show they don't raise people out of poverty. Then note that people who have been raised out of poverty were so done by capitalism. Not by some unknown mechanism but explitly and openly by capitalism."

Comment: Yeah, no. This is wrong. The explosion of wealth built on a series of major technological innovations in the 18th and 19th centuries. Most of which were discovered by the gentleman scientists, who definitely were not motivated by capitalist impulses.

Comment: Also the graph itself is a fraud. Every single chart of something that increases logarithmically looks like that - seemingly flat and then with a huge increase at the end. It looks like it's suddenly taken off for some reason, but in reality it's been increasing at the same rate all along, it's just the early increases get lost. Here's an example of the same graph, showing the same behaviour, except the chart stops at 1820. https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/world-gdp-over-the-last-two-millennia?time=1..1820